# Using if condition in datetime format

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-datetime

I was given a question to get two time input from user as a function(opening_time,closing_time) and I had to determine the difference between the time,but if one of these values are not in time format,the returned value should be -1.I have computed the time difference but,I am unable to fix a condition that if any one of the variable is not in time format,return -1.
Please I am new to coding,so apologize for any mistake and be kind to write simple solution,not so complex one.

```
from datetime import datetime
def compute_opening_duration(opening_time, closing_time):
    str_format = "%H:%M:%S"
    if opening_time or closing_time != datetime.time.str_format:
        print(-1)
    else:
        tdelta = datetime.strptime(closing_time,str_format) 
             - datetime.strptime(opening_time,str_format)
        print(tdelta)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it will try to cast the inputs to a datetime using your provided string format. If it fails on either one, it will print -1.

```
from datetime import datetime
def compute_opening_duration(opening_time, closing_time):
    str_format = "%H:%M:%S"
    try:
        t_open_time = datetime.strptime(closing_time,str_format)
        t_closing_time = datetime.strptime(opening_time,str_format)
        tdelta = datetime.strptime(closing_time,str_format) - datetime.strptime(opening_time,str_format)
        print(tdelta)
    except:
        print(-1)

compute_opening_duration("04:10:21", "08:22:12")
```